# Как получить данные от родителя к ребенку через Props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Добрый вечер.
Есть такой код:

```js
const SubWrapper = {
  template: '#sub-wrapper',
  
  data: function () {
    return {
      width: ''
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    handleResize () {
          this.width = this.$el.clientWidth
    }
  },
  
  mounted: function () {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
        this.width = this.$el.clientWidth;
    })
  }
};

const MyTemplateCanvas = {
  template: '#my-template-canvas',
  
  props:['name'],
  
  data () {
    return {
      configKonva: {
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        stroke:'gray'
      },
      configCircle2: {
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        width: 260,
        height: 160,
        fill: "gray",
        stroke: "#2a1725",
        strokeWidth: 2
      }
    }
  }
};

Vue.use('VueKonva');

const root = new Vue({
  el: '.wrapper',
  components: {
    SubWrapper,
    MyTemplateCanvas
  }
});
```

```css
div, span, a, ul, li, dl, dt, dd, fieldset, form, label, button, input, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, strong, p, br, i, figure, figcaption {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0 none;
}

:focus {
    border: 0 none;
}

button, a:hover, label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

li {
    list-style: none outside none;
}

img {
    border: medium none;
}

a:active, a:focus, img, input, textarea {
    outline: none;
}

a:active {
    background-color: transparent;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
    overflow: auto;
}

th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper .sub_wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.konvajs-content{
    width: 100% ! important;
}
.wrapper .sub_wrapper canvas{
    background-color: #c0c0c0 ! important;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>MK Trading</title>
  <link href="style/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <sub-wrapper name="width">
      <my-template-canvas></my-template-canvas>
    </sub-wrapper>
  </div>

  <script id="sub-wrapper" type="text/x-template">
    <div class="sub_wrapper">
    <resize-observer @notify="handleResize" />
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script id="my-template-canvas" type="text/x-template">
    <v-stage ref="stage" :config="configKonva">
      <v-layer ref="layer">
        <v-rect ref="zzz" :config="configCircle2"></v-rect>
      </v-layer>
    </v-stage>
  </script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-resize@0.4.3/dist/vue-resize.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/konva'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/vue-konva'></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вопрос:
Как в данной конфигурации(кода) правильно прописать(с синтаксической точки зрения для HTML и JS файлов)
св-ва(в родителе(sub-wrapper) и в ребенке(my-template-canvas)) что бы можно было считывать(в том числе и динамически) данные из родительского блока?
Что только не пробовал уже - всегда или андефайнд выдает или ошибку в консоли..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вы пропс объявили в MyTemplateCanvas, а передаете в SubWrapper.
Конечно не будет работать.
Я бы сделал так, хоть это и плохая практика:
https://jsfiddle.net/mkt1m5o0/

```js
const SubWrapper = {
  name: 'SubWrapper',
  template: '#sub-wrapper',
  data () {
    return {
      width: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleResize () {
      this.width = this.$el.clientWidth
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.width = this.$el.clientWidth
    })
  }
}

const MyTemplateCanvas = {
  name: 'MyTemplateCanvas',
  template: '#my-template-canvas',
  watch: {
   name (name) {
     console.log('name:', name)
   }
  },
  computed: {
   name () {
     return this.$parent.width
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      configKonva: {
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        stroke:'gray'
      },
      configCircle2: {
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        width: 260,
        height: 160,
        fill: "gray",
        stroke: "#2a1725",
        strokeWidth: 2
      }
    }
  }
}

Vue.use('VueKonva')

const root = new Vue({
  el: '.wrapper',
  components: {
    SubWrapper,
    MyTemplateCanvas
  }
})
```

```css
div, span, a, ul, li, dl, dt, dd, fieldset, form, label, button, input, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, strong, p, br, i, figure, figcaption {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0 none;
}

:focus {
    border: 0 none;
}

button, a:hover, label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

li {
    list-style: none outside none;
}

img {
    border: medium none;
}

a:active, a:focus, img, input, textarea {
    outline: none;
}

a:active {
    background-color: transparent;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
    overflow: auto;
}

th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper .sub_wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.konvajs-content{
    width: 100% ! important;
}
.wrapper .sub_wrapper canvas{
    background-color: #c0c0c0 ! important;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>MK Trading</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <sub-wrapper>
      <my-template-canvas></my-template-canvas>
    </sub-wrapper>
  </div>

  <script id="sub-wrapper" type="text/x-template">
    <div class="sub_wrapper">
     <resize-observer
       @notify="handleResize"
      />
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script id="my-template-canvas" type="text/x-template">
    <v-stage ref="stage" :config="configKonva">
      <v-layer ref="layer">
        <v-rect ref="zzz" :config="configCircle2"></v-rect>
      </v-layer>
    </v-stage>
  </script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-resize@0.4.3/dist/vue-resize.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/konva'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/vue-konva'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А вы не могли бы пример именно с помощью Props показать работающий?
Уже куда только не пихал эти св-ва(в js и html) - всегда или андефайнд или ошибка в консоли.
Хотелось бы понять именно механику работы Props.

Comment: И еще такой вопрос:
если можно прописать 'this.$parent.width' - зачем тогда вообще необходим Props?
(в чем преимущество такого подхода?)

Comment: Подход, использованный мной, плохой. Плох он тем, что вы теряете возможность переиспользования дочернего компонента без вмешательства в его код.
Просто в вашем приведенном варианте это на мой взгляд единственное изящное решение. Можно конечно еще и provide/inject использовать, но там свойства не реактивны.

Comment: Вот вам пример с использованием props: https://jsfiddle.net/mkt1m5o0/1/

Comment: такой вопрос еще забыл уточнить:
можно ли как то обращаться к элементу по айдишнику или по ref из другого елемента?
не через пропс вытаскивать данные а напрямую обращаться?
(не только к родителю но и к детям и братьям например.)
Если да - то является ли это плохим подходом?